# Cloudant CDTDatastore to pull only part of the database

Tags: cloudant

We're using Cloudant as the remote database for our app. The database contains documents for each user of the app. When the app launches, we need to query the database for all the documents belonging to a user. What we found is the CDTDatastore API only allows pulling the entire database and storing it inside the app then performing the query in the local copy. The initial pulling to the local datastore takes about 10 seconds and I imagine will take longer when adding more users.

Is there a way I can save only part of the remote database to the local datastore? Or, are we using the wrong service for our app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a server side [replication filter function](https://docs.cloudant.com/replication_guide.html); you'll need to add information about your filter to the pull replicator. However replication will have a performance hit when using the function.

That being said a common pattern is to use one database per user, however this has other trade offs and it is something you should read up on. There is some information on the one database per user pattern [here](https://cloudant.com/blog/replication-with-cloudant-pt-3/#.VtTef0XfWnM).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the one database per user, as using the replication filter made the initial pull slower.